# Как передать в grep критерии через поток

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

У меня есть файл с словами "vocabulary.txt" и есть файл с маленьким рассказом "loveStory.txt". 
Задача: вывести все слова из "loveStory.txt", что **не** встречаются в "vocabulary.txt".

К чему я пришел:

```
$ grep -oL $(egrep -o '[a-z]+' loveStory.txt) vocabulary.txt
```

Постараюсь объяснить свою мысль:

```
#1
$(egrep -o '[a-z]+' loveStory.txt) 
# возвращает каждое слово из "loveStory.txt" с новой строки

#2
grep -oL <возвращаемые значения из \#1> vocabulary.txt
#получив слова он должен сказать есть ли оно там
```

НО дело в том, что #2 считает, что я ему передаю пути в файлы в которых надо искать.
Уверен, что #2 не верно сделан с целью получить слова, что **не** находятся в vocabulary, но мне бы сделать так чтобы он воспринимал слова, что возвращаются #1 как критерии.

Comment: Попробуйте так - 1) `words="$(grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' vocabulary.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')"`, 2) `diff="$(sed -E "s/\b($words)\b//g" "loveStory.txt)"`, 3) `grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' <<< "$diff"`, [демо](https://ideone.com/TrNrNE)

Comment: Опечатка, должно быть 2) `diff="$(sed -E "s/\b($words)\b//g" loveStory.txt)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это следующим образом:

- Получить список целых слов из vocabulary.txt и создать шаблон типа `word1|word2|wordN` (`words="$(grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' vocabulary.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')"`)
- Удалить все совпадения целых слов из loveStory.txt (`diff="$(sed -E "s/\b($words)\b//g" loveStory.txt)"`)
- Получить список слов из того, что получилось в результате предыдущего действия, `grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' <<< "$diff"`.

Код:

```
words="$(grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' vocabulary.txt | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')"
diff="$(sed -E "s/\b($words)\b//g" loveStory.txt)"
grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' <<< "$diff"
```

[Демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/TrNrNE):

```
voc="love story"
loveStory="read about new love story"
words="$(grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' <<< "$voc" | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//')"
diff="$(sed -E "s/\b($words)\b//g" <<< "$loveStory")"
grep -oE '\b[[:alpha:]]+\b' <<< "$diff"
```

Результат

```
read
about
new
```

Answer (score 1):

а ещё можно воспользоваться и программой *comm*. для поиска входящих / не входящих слов (ну, вообще, конечно, строк, но в данном случае каждое слово на отдельной строке, потому строка==слово).

пример:

```
$ cat story 
однажды в студёную зимнюю
$ cat vocabulary 
однажды
в
$ comm -1 -3 <(sort vocabulary) <(grep -o '[[:alpha:]]\+' story | sort)
зимнюю
студёную
```

пояснения:

- `sort файл` или `команда | sort` — сортировать строки
- `программа <(команда)` — формирует из *stdout* `команды` временный файловый дескриптор и передаёт его в качестве аргумента `программе` (см. `$ man bash`, секция `Process Substitution`)
- `comm -1 -3 файл1 файл2`:

  - `-1` — убрать из вывода строки, уникальные для первого файла
  - `-3` — убрать из вывода строки, общие для обоих файлов

  фактически, остаются только строки, уникальные для второго файла. файлы, кстати, должны быть отсортированы.

p.s. а если добавить программе *sort* опцию `-u`, то после сортировки останутся только уникальные строки.